# filter marker based on radius react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to display markers based on radius and I'm unable to develop a logic for that. My locations for markers come from firestore geopoint. I have successfully filter the marker based on category from my firestore but i'm unable filter it by maximum distance radius

MY problem: I dont know how to use radius property and where to put that property and based on radius how to filter the markers

```js
class mapView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      users:[],
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: -6.64064,
        longitude:  106.8273983,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      },
    }
  }

getLocation(){
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude
          var long = position.coords.longitude

          var initialRegion ={
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          }
          this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
      },
      (error) => {
        // See error code charts below.
        console.log(error.code, error.message); 
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
  );
  }

fetchRequests(){
    this.subscriber = firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users").onSnapshot(docs => {
        let users = []
        docs.forEach(doc => {
          users.push(doc.data())
        })
        this.setState({users})
        console.log(users)
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
    this.fetchRequests();
    this.getLocation();
  }

render() {

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView  
            showsUserLocation={true}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}>
            {this.state.users.filter(element => element.golDarah === this.props.currentUser.golDarah && element.geo_point.latitude 
            !== this.props.currentUser.geo_point.latitude && element.locationOn === true )
            .map((user, idx) => <Marker
            key={idx}
            coordinate={{latitude: user.geo_point.latitude, longitude: user.geo_point.longitude}}
            >
              <Callout>
              <View style={{height: 0.1 * windowHeight()}}>
                <Text>Nama: {user.name}</Text>
                <Text>Golongan Darah: {user.golDarah}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL(`${user.noHp}`)}}>
                  <Text>No HP:{user.noHp}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </Callout>
               
            </Marker>)}
            </MapView>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: First just a style point: it might be time to consider moving a lot of that logic out of the JSX. When it comes the radius, once you've retrieved/calculated that, it is a simple matter of iterating over the geolocations provided with the points. The purpose is to calculate the distance from your center point for each geolocation. Then it is a simple matter of comparing the radius with the distance of the geopoint.

Comment: @RandyCasburn could you give me some code example?

Comment: @RandyCasburn i'm still confused with what you say